# update record in structure in c++

Tags: c++

I am writing c++ application to store info about products, these info include ID,name,cost.

if the user chooses an ID then a new name he will be able to update the name of this product, but this really doesn't work :(

here is my code for update:

```
bool HASH::updateName(int id,product &product1,char newName[100])
{
    int start,index;
    start=HF(id);

    for (int i=0; i<((n+1)/2);i++)
    {
        index=(int)(start+i*i)%n;

        if(!products[index].full)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if(products[index].ID==id)
        {
            strcpy(product1.name,newName);

            memcpy(&product1,&products[index],sizeof(product));

            return true;
        }

    }


}
```

this is the product structure:

```
struct product{
public:
    int ID;
    int cost;
    int quantity;
    char name[100];
    bool full;}
```

I used it in a class called HASH to store the products in a hash table

Comment: have you tried some debuger?

Comment: @V-X it enters the else statement but doesn't update the record, is there something wrong in my code??

Comment: never use memcpy to copy a C++ object unless it's a POD. Use copy constructor or copy assignment.

Comment: @bolov I don't think the problem with memcpy, because I used in another function to add records and it works fine

Comment: @roa.tah using memcpy on a non-POD object results in undefined behaviour, so the fact that it worked in another context doesn't mean it is ok.

Comment: Provide the definition and declaration of product and i'll look over it and provide with an answer if there is a problem there.

Comment: @bolov how could I use copy assignment?? check the edit

Comment: @roa.tah. product is a POD so it should be ok. You have the destination and Source reversed. I still advise to use the assignment operator over memcpy.

Comment: you can do: product1.name = newName. Cast it to string, it has overloaded operators.

Comment: @PnDs " product1.name = newName" He CAN'T do that since he uses C-strings.

Comment: yep, my bad I haven't thought on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`memcpy(&product1,&products[index],sizeof(product));` It looks like you have destination and source interchanged. It is `void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );`

I strongly suggest using `operator=` over memcpy for objects:

`products[index] = product1`